# Font Awesome Icons Not Showing On IE and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, font-awesome

Simple question, yet I cannot seem to find a working solution anywhere. I am using the Font Awesome Library, saved in a file, in a static site. I put in the following code into a login link.

```
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
```

Which on Google Chrome brings up a little lock icon right next to "Login". However when I check on IE or Firefox, it disappears. Is there a reason that this happens, and if so is there a work around? I don't have any code to provide except for the one above because I'm simply at a loss. Do I need to somehow code in cases for the various browsers?

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting , This should help. Particularly <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch. I guess a lot of it has to do with how the client has their browser set up. Put this in an answer so I can accept it. Big help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: That was the simplest fix to any of the problems I've had in quite a while.